How to fill a face between two separate objects?
I have to fill a face between two edges that are parallel to each other but belong to two different objects. Is it possible to achieve this ?

No, you can't, they are 2 separate objects

Do you want them to stay separate objects? If so, then no that's not possible. If you want them to become a single object, you can join them with Ctrl+J, this makes them a single object. Then you can connect them with a face by selecting the two edges and pressing F.

Yes it is possible. First, make multiple selections by pressing Shift+Alt keys in Edit Mode on the vertices of those two objects that you want to combine. Then, just press the F key to create a surface between.

No. The question says different objects, not different meshes. Even when you select both objects and switch to Edit Mode so that you can select vertices or edges on both objects, pressing F will not create a face between them. And by the way with Shift+Alt you will add a loop selection, but nowhere was stated that loops need to be selected for the question.
